# Can't run Yii 2.0 cmd tool on Linux EC2 AWS

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-ec2, cmd, yii2

I've developed an application locally using Yii 2.0 framework (on a windows machine). And since i've installed the framewrok i was able to go to the projects folder and tun .\yii and see a list of commands that i could run. I use a lot of custom commands for this application that i have developed.

the thing is that i just uploaded my application to an EC2 instance on AWS, and for some reaon the framework works fine ( i can run my app) but i can't run .\yii on the script shell.

It is a Linux Instance

I've searched a lot for answers but i didn't find anything!

I've tried running: yii, .\yii, ./yii  none of tem work, it seems like the cmd doesn't recognize the shell script, the error that i get is:

-bash: sudo: command not found

So, am i forgetting some configuration that i should have done for thi to work? How do i make it work??

---

### Update

I was checking the yii.bat file contents:

```
@echo off
rem -------------------------------------------------------------
rem  Yii command line bootstrap script for Windows.
rem
rem  @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
rem  @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
rem  @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
rem  @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
rem -------------------------------------------------------------

@setlocal

set YII_PATH=%~dp0

if "%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=php.exe

"%PHP_COMMAND%" "%YII_PATH%yii" %*
```

So it is saying:  Yii command line bootstrap script for Windows

i don't understand about shell scripts, but the first thing that commes to my mind as obvious is that it wouldn't work on Linux, because it is a Windows command line tool. 
The problem is i haven't found any source containing a Linux/Unix command line tool for Yii 2.0

Anyone knows where i can find it?
Or how do i make this run on Linux?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys, if you are uploading a Yii 2.0 windows project to a Linux server and need the command line tool to work, here's what you do:

Download on your server the template you are using (basic or advanced) using composer. Then you are gonna copy some files and replace it on your original project. They are:

> composer.json composer.lock LICENSE.md README.md requirements.php yii
>   yii.bat

Probably you only need yii and yii.bat, but i replaced all the ones i've listed.